# En dash gets sent as â€“ to the database

Tags: php, unicode, utf-8

I have a small site with a few forms.

The type of the document is UTF-8:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

When I write an en dash (–) it gets converted to â€“ and when hitting submit on a form with an en dash somewhere in the fields it causes the page to fail updating.

This is driving me crazy. Why is this happening?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through). You're forgetting to use UTF-8 somewhere in the process: there's a comprehensive checklist in the linked question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything must be explicitly set to UTF-8: The database fields, the HTML document, and (most critically) the *connection* between PHP and MySQL.

The exact way to do this depends on what library you are using. For instance, with the old `mysql` library, it's [`mysql_set_charset`](http://php.net/mysql-set-charset)